# Decrypting a file using MD5CryptoServiceProvider, TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider and ICryptoTransform

Tags: c#, streamwriter

Anyone familiar with the use of MD5CryptoServiceProvider, TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider and ICryptoTransform? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTopW.jpg)
I successfully encrypted a file and wrote it with StreamWriter to a text file, but trouble arises when reading the file with StreamReader and seeking to decrypt the text.

The error message claims that "the input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

The file has been encrypted by using the following code:

```
string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
string hash = (encrypted file here);
byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash);
using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
{
byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = keys, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
{
ICryptoTransform transforms = tripDes.CreateEncryptor();
byte[] results = transforms.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);hash = Convert.ToBase64String(results, 0, results.Length);
}
```

The decrypting code is as follows:

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(text source here);
using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
{
byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text source here));
using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = keys, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
{
ICryptoTransform transforms = tripDes.CreateDecryptor();
byte[] results = transforms.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
(text source here) = UTF32Encoding.UTF8.GetString(results);
}
}
```

I tried it with all padding options to no avail. Any insights, suggestions or educated guesses on how to solve the problem?

Is StreamWriter known to add extra characters to the encrypted text that causes this problem? If so, what method do you recommend for the encrypting and decrypting a file in C#?

Comment: Why are you tring to convert bytes to base64? You can save byte array to file using this method: File.WriteAllBytes. On the other hand you can read file using File.ReadAllBytes

Comment: Here is a decent example of what you want to use: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/tripledes-encryption-in-c-sharp/